# WPF MultiThread

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, task

I need to load a large file and present the data in a datagrid, but some how i can not load the file asynchronously.

**the Button Code:**

```
private async void MILoadLogFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    ...
        await myLogSession.LoadfromFileAsync(oFD.FileName);
    }
}
```

**and the Load Method**

```
public async Task LoadfromFileAsync(String fileName) {

    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);

    String line;
    try {
        using (streamReader) {
            while ((line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null) {

                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("DOOOOOOOOOOOOONE");
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

}

This One Works but it is not Smooth at all, I cant move the window

Comment: What do you mean you can't load it asynchronously?

Comment: you need the `async` keyword on the `LoadFromFileAsync` method. Otherwise, you cannot use `await`

Comment: I get "A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll" and nothing shows

Comment: I tried to format your code but there are so many `}`.. Could you post the actual code that you are using?

Comment: Where do you get that exception?

Comment: im not sure, but my guess is that Im editing the UI thread from other thread

Comment: 1) `testLoad` really shouldn't exist as a method...just get rid of it.  Call `LoadfromFileAsync` directly. 2) `async` methods should basically never be `void` unless you're attaching them as an event handler.  `LoadfromFileAsync` should return a `Task` if there is no data to return, or `Task<Something>` if it has something to actually return.  The caller can choose to ignore the returned task if needed, but you should provide it regardless.

Comment: Please post the call stack.

Comment: I have edit the Code now, im not sure what to return in LoadfromFileAsync.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
private async void MILoadLogFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await myLogSession.LoadfromFileAsync(oFD.FileName);
    });
}
```

Comment: I Get: `The program '[2488] LogViewerGUI.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`And `The program '[2488] LogViewerGUI.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0)`

Comment: How can i Run this from a dispather?

Comment: Check the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` example here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)